# Words from ArcPy Scripts Appear in Map Document?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I created a slope map of the U.S. using ArcPy scripts (ArcGIS 10.2). I just completed the map. However, some of the words from my ArcPy scripts show up in the map document, both in data and layout views. I need to remove this print from the map. [image: Print from ArcPy Script in Map Document]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably these are text elements so you should be able to go into Layout or Data View of ArcMap and use the Select tool from the Draw toolbar to click on them, and then hit the Delete key to remove them.

If this works, but next time you run your ArcPy script they come back, then you will need to try and debug your script.

Comment: Using the Draw toolbar worked. However, I couldn't just select the text and delete it. I had to place a text box over segments of the words and delete the text box to erase the words.

Comment: By "place a text box" I think you are describing dragging a selection rectangle.  That would make sense because it may not be easy to always see precisely the extent of the text box the text is in.

Comment: Have you tried clicking the refresh icon near the bottom of the layout view. When you place a text box over them and delete it they disappear seems like maybe they aren't really text elements but maybe 'artifacts'. For instance I have had this occur with labels that pop up at certain zoom levels but sometimes get 'stuck' when I zoom out and a refresh will get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to see which words are appearing in your layout. Are they all related somehow? Are they all lines in your script that are commented out?

Do these lines of text appear in data view also? Or just the layout view?

I would check these things out and see if there was a specific pattern of which are appearing. Then you could maybe try running it again without certain lines and see what happens.