# Text that remains without any active layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, text

I think this might be a simple question to answer, but I'm not sure how to do it. I turned off all the layers in my .mxd file, and I still have text that shows up on the screen. I don't know if I accidentally added this or something, but I don't know how to get rid of it. [image]

Comment: Please add a picture of the table of contents and text that appears on your screen. It is unclear what the problem without it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a text element or annotation.  Use the select tool (black arrow), draw a box around it or click on it, and hit the delete button on your keyboard.

Comment: You could open a new, blank mxd and add the layers to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try clicking the 'Refresh' button near the bottom of the map window, also see the comments for the selected answer of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131884/words-from-arcpy-scripts-appear-in-map-document/131887#comment189227_131887), seem like the text box may be a work around if the above doesn't work.

[image]